# Using merTools::predictInterval for Poisson family mixed models

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, poisson

I am utilizing the `predictInterval()` function from the `merTools` package. My model is fit utilizing a Poisson family specification like the below:

```
glmer(y ~ (1|key) + x, data = dat, family = poisson())
```

When I use `predictInterval()` to calculate the prediction interval associated with my model, I get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
     Prediction for NLMMs or GLMMs that are not mixed binomial regressions is not tested. Sigma set at 1.
```

I am taking this to mean that `predictInterval()` doesn't have an implementation for models fit with a Poisson distribution. I therefore do not trust the resulting interval.

Is my interpretation correct? I have searched around for similar issues but haven't found anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `metTools` work primarily within the boundaries of *linear mixed effect models*. The world gets a lot more complicated in generalized models, as there are no closed solutions and various approximation are used for estimating parameters, so the warning is (as you correctly interpret) that these are not to be trusted. 
If you are looking for confidence intervals and prediction intervals various bootstrapping methods or estimating using bayesian alternatives provide much more reliable estimates.

Comment: Thanks for your very thoughtful input.